# The flexibility of phrasal verbs

Tags: phrasal-verbs

1)
put the phone down = put down the phone

2)
put a baby down = put down a baby.

3)
put an amendment down = put down an amendment.

Does the preposition 'down' in those phrasal verbs have a flexible position around the object?

If not, why not?

Comment: When one puts down something which is living, it ceases to live. One puts down an animal; putting down a baby might be seen as a bit barbaric.

Comment: In that phrasal verb, I did mean to say "I put a baby to bed".

Comment: @Andrew: In the U.S., if one is holding a puppy, one can put it down without killing it. I am sure that this is true in the U.K. as well. I also think there's a U.S. idiom *"put a baby down"* meaning to get him to go to sleep in his bed/crib, although I can't find any examples of it on the web, so it may be rare.

Comment: @Andrew: Found it! *"I put Jimmy down for a nap after lunch."* [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zygjbvn0N0kC&pg=PT67&lpg=PT67&dq=%22put+Jimmy+down+for+a+nap%22&source=bl&ots=vmzuPQW4iu&sig=84kWXhwgA36v71BcNfcXR6srQd8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMIr5mRsLi1xwIVA5WACh0GJgTx#v=onepage&q=%22put%20Jimmy%20down%20for%20a%20nap%22&f=false).

Comment: It's not *down* that has the flexible position it's the object of the preposition that can move.

Comment: Yes but moving the object can change the meaning; we put babies down (=put to bed) in the UK too. What we don't do is put down babies.

Comment: *Your baby's so dumb he couldn't fall off the table if you set him on the edge.*

Comment: I'm not sure why you're calling 'down' a preposition here. I'm not sure that even intransitive preposition fans would accept it as such.

Answer (score 1):

As user 5jj posted on [usingenglish.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/200413-turn-it-on-look-after-it-Phrasal-verbs-object-pronoun-position)...

> *Unfortunately for learners, there are many different types of what are loosely called 'phrasal verbs'.*

He identifies Verb + Preposition, Verb + particle, Prepositional Verb, Phrasal Verb, Intransitive verbs followed by a particle/adverb, and Intransitive phrasal verbs as the 6 main subtypes, each with different constraints on how they can be validly used.

But probably the main constraint for most constructions called "phrasal verbs" is that if there's an *object*, and if that object is expressed as a *pronoun*, it must appear ***between the verb and the preposition***. Thus...

> *She **told** him **off*** (valid idiomatic phrasal verb meaning *She rebuked him*)
>    *She **told off** him* (not a valid construction)

---

By *my* definition of "phrasal verb", OP's examples #1 and #3 simply aren't (they're just ordinary "literal" usages). The true phrasal verb ***put down*** has two possible primary senses...

> *Mary put down the old dog* (she either *denigrated* or *euthanized* it)
>    *She put it down* (valid phrasal verb as above, ***or*** the literal sense ***placed*** [in a lower position])
>    *She put down it* (never valid)

Comment: Here, essentially, the usage in (1) is literal and transitive (put = place) with locative/directional particle, optionally separable from the verb for non-pronouns. But  'run the kids over' (accepting 'run' as virtually literal) is  mandatorily separable in the happier sense. // (3) is metaphorical (put down = table) and transitive, and again optionally separable. // (2) is ambiguous. 'Put down' with the literal transitive sense here is optionally separable, as in (1), but with the separated version preferred because the unseparated carries the 'euthanise' sense more strongly....

Comment: However, the metaphorical euthanise sense (_and_ the denigrate sense) is optionally separable.

Comment: Interesting bit about the pronoun. I suppose that explains why we can say, "She put down Jim" (meaning, she _insulted_ Jim), but we can't say, "She put down him."

Comment: @J.R.: In the right context you can just about put the pronoun at the end in a phrasal verb usage. *My neighbour is so mean he put his sick dog down rather than pay the vet for antibiotics. Grrrr! I'd like to put down **him**!*

Answer (score 0):

The compound particle can often change its place before or after an object.

- Put on your hat - Put your hat on
- Turn off the heating - Turn the heating off
- Switch on the radio - Switch the radio off
- Put down that gun - Put that gun down
- Put up your hands -Put your hands up

Up to now I haven't found the rule that defines exactly when the changing is possible. I think only with some very frequent particles.

In some cases this changing of place is not possible. Modern dictionaries indicate when the particle can change place with a special sign.

Oald has a vertical stroke with two arrow-heads on both sides.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/put-up

I've just consulted the Longman grammar by Alexander to see what he says. The grammar point is treated in section 8.28 and I see that is quite a tricky problem.